# CSS add line before and after the image

Tags: html, css

I have an image like so:

```
<a href="#landing">
  <img src="button.png" style="display:block; margin-top:10px; margin:0 auto;" />
</a>
```

What I am looking to do is to add a line before and after the image, with the image being centred.

Like so:

------------------- Image ---------------------

I am having trouble understanding the whole `:before` and `:after` thing. My question is how do I add a line before and after the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `Flexbox`. You can vertically center **img** and **lines** with `align-items: center` also with `flex: 1` `:before` and `:after` will take remaining width.

```css
a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
a:before,
a:after {
  flex: 1;
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the line on a pseudo element, and adjust the positions as needed.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gzs5cgs/)**

```css
a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
a:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  background: green;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="//dummyimage.com/50">
</a>
```